# Label beside input (bootstrap form)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-form-helper

I tried coding this but i dont get the expected output, i also tried to use inline but it doesnt work too.

maybe someone can help me show the expected output. thank you

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                        <!-- Row -->
                        <div class="row gx-4 mb-1">
                        
                        <!-- -->
                         <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label class="small mb-1" for="">Student name</label>
                         <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="" type="text" value=""/>
                        </div>
                        
                        <!--  -->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label class="small mb-1" for="">Address</label>
                         <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="" type="text" value=""/>
                        </div>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        <!-- Row -->
                        <div class="row gx-4 mb-1">
                        
                        <!-- -->
                         <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label class="small mb-1" for="">ID Number</label>
                         <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="" type="text" value=""/>
                        </div>
                        
                        <!--  -->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label class="small mb-1" for="">Email</label>
                         <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="" type="text" value=""/>
                        </div>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        </form>
```

[here is the sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJqAa.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the `label` and `input` in a `row` with **2-10** columns should do it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row px-4 mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-6 row mb-3">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
                Label
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 row mb-3">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
                Label
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="row px-4 mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-6 row mb-3">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
                Label
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 row mb-3">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
                Label
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can adjust the padding/margin according to your needs.